# Migrate ADF - Datasets which are linked with Linked Services and Pipelines to Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

We Need to migrate Datasets from ADF which are linked with Linked Services and Pipelines only to Synapse Analytics.

The GITHUB solution (from previous posts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/533505/import-bulk-pipelines-from-azure-data-factory-to-a.html)
migrates entire all datasets, pipelines, linked services from ADF to Synapse Analytics.

But we need to migrate Datasets, linked services and pipelines which are linked each other and don't need to migrate which were not linked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to exclude the unwanted objects from Azure Data Factory when migrating to other service (Synapse Analytics in your case).

As a workaround, you can make a copy of the existing factory, remove the objects you do not wish to migrate, and use that new factory as your source.

Please follow the below steps to copy the existing data factory objects to new data factory.

1. Go to your existing ADF Workspace. Follow the path: **Manage -> ARM templates -> Export ARM template.**

[image]

2. Extract the downloaded file. Open the `arm_template.json` file in Notepad++ or any other editor. On line number 8, for parameter `defaultValue`, give the name of your new data factory where you will copy the objects.
3. Create a new Azure Data Factory with the same name which you have provided in the above step.
4. Go the Workspace of this newly created data factory. Follow the path: **Manage -> ARM template -> Import ARM template.** This will open a separate **Custom deployment** tab.
5. Select **Build your own template in the editor** option.

[image]

6. Delete the existing content on whitespace. Click on **Load file** option to upload the `arm_template.json` file which you downloaded and edited earlier. Click on **Save**.

[image]

7. In the final step, you need to give **Subscription**, **Resource Group**, **Region** and **Name of newly created data factory** where all your objects will be copied. Along with that, **you need to provide the connection string of all the linked services which will be copied in the new factory.** See the below image  for reference. Once done, click on **Review and Create** and this will copy all your objects to new Data Factory.

[image]

Now, in your new factory, you can delete all the objects which you don't want to migrate. Once done, follow the same GitHub link which is mentioned in Microsoft Q&A answer to migrate the objects to Synapse Analytics.

**Note:** You can later delete the resources (data factory which is used for migration).